# Python: Time prints as 00:00:00 when using datetime.time() module

Tags: python

I am working on making calibrations for the Raspberry Pi Weather Station I have created using the Sense HAT. The offset between the actual temperature and the reading received from the Pi increases at a certain time of day (when the sun hits the system). I want to subtract a larger number from the Sense HAT temp during this time and revert to the lower number at all other instances.

I attempted to use datetime module to set up the beginning and and end times for the more significant calibration. I set up the current time in a separate variable.

```
time = datetime.time()

time_start = datetime.time(12,30,00)

time_end = datetime.time(3,15,00)

if time_start < time and time_end > time:

     temperature -= 10

else:

     temperature -= 8
```

I expected the output to be a lower temperature reading but the program continues to subtract 8 degrees during this period instead of 10. I did some troubleshooting and when printing the "time" variable it prints as "00:00:00". This would explain why the program skips to the else statement and only subtracts 8.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You are probably looking for `datetime.now()`, not `datetime.time()`

Comment: try time.asctime() and see what it prints

Comment: Along with the fix suggested, you can combine the comparisons: `if time_start < time < time_end:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `datetime.time()` is the equivalent of using `time(0, 0, 0)`.

What you want instead is to obtain the current time, which you can do through `datetime.now()`.

```py
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime.now().time()

time_start = datetime.time(12,30,00)

time_end = datetime.time(3,15,00)

if time_start < time and time_end > time:

     temperature -= 10

else:

     temperature -= 8
```